# Multiple vlc-python errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, libvlc, python-vlc

I am trying to make a media explorer using the vlc-python library and tkinter. But I keep getting multiple errors. There errors occur in seemingly random order and only after pressing <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd>. Pressing these buttons multiple times quickly sometimes causes the program to crash. Folder contains only images and videos. I am just including the unique errors :-

```
[000001e7a8e0b2a0] cache_read stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
[000001e7ae098ee0] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek
[000001e7ae286d30] direct3d11 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[000001e7b6be89f0] avcodec decoder: Using D3D11VA (Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500, vendor 8086(Intel), device 1616, revision 9) for hardware decoding
[h264 @ 000001e7a90b1040] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 000001e7a90b1040] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 000001e7a90b1040] decode_slice_header error
[000001e7ae0fcbc0] direct3d11 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[000001dceaa2c890] mmdevice audio output error: cannot initialize COM (error 0x80010106)
```

Sometimes when I play videos, the playback continually lags and the following error is logged every time it lags,

```
[h264 @ 000001e7a90b1040] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 000001e7a90b1040] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 000001e7a90b1040] decode_slice_header error
```

The code:

```py
from time import sleep
import vlc
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os


class Player(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title=None):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.base = ""
        self.files = ""
        self.currFile = -1
        self.parent = parent

        if title == None:
            title = "Project"
        self.parent.title(title)

        self.videopanel = ttk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.canvas = Tk.Canvas(self.videopanel).pack(fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.videopanel.pack(fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.sortOptions = ttk.Frame(self.parent)
        ttk.Button(self.sortOptions, text="Open...",
                   command=self.OnOpen).pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
        self.sortOptions.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

        self.player = None

    def OnOpen(self):
        self.OnStop()
        currfolder = next(os.walk(askdirectory()))
        self.base = currfolder[0]
        self.files = []
        for file in currfolder[2]:
            if(file.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.mp4', '.mkv', '.mp3'))):
                self.files.append(file)
        
        for child in self.sortOptions.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()

        self.player = vlc.Instance().media_player_new()
        self.player.set_hwnd(self.videopanel.winfo_id())

        self.parent.bind("<Right>", lambda e: self.nextFile(e))
        self.parent.bind("<Left>", lambda e: self.nextFile(e, False))
        
        self.nextFile()

    def nextFile(self, event=None, next=True):
        self.OnStop()

        if(next):
            self.currFile += 1
            if(self.currFile == len(self.files)):
                self.currFile = 0
        else:
            self.currFile -= 1
            if(self.currFile == -1):
                self.currFile = len(self.files)-1

        filePath = os.path.join(self.base, self.files[self.currFile])

        self.player.set_media(vlc.Media(filePath))

        self.OnPlay()
        return

    def errorDialog(self, errormessage):
        Tk.tkMessageBox.showerror(self, 'Error', errormessage)

    def OnPlay(self):
        if not self.player.get_media():
            self.OnOpen()
        else:
            if self.player.play() == -1:
                self.errorDialog("Unable to play.")

    def OnStop(self):
        if(self.player):
            pass
            self.player.pause()


def Tk_get_root():
    if not hasattr(Tk_get_root, "root"):
        Tk_get_root.root = Tk.Tk()
    return Tk_get_root.root


def _quit():
    print("_quit: bye")
    root = Tk_get_root()
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()
    os._exit(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk_get_root()
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", _quit)

    player = Player(root, title="Project")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you checked what is in `self.files`? I see nothing obvious in the code to suggest that you are limiting the file types to audio/video.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I made some edits to my code with the advice you gave, but it still didn't make any changes.